# Display JSON in table with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to display table of data from objects with plan to also have a collapsible detail of the properties for each store but for now I am struggling to display anything other than the first value. Any help appreciated. I looked at many other examples but being a newbie I can't get my head around them so hoping understanding my exact scenario first will allow me figure out more on my own.

Tried return multiple calls with for loop but returns just one element and exits.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class DataStores extends Component {
  state = [

    {
      name:"PODs",
      storeType:"fixed",
      properties: [
        {
          name:"PODNo",
          type: "text",
          regex: ""
        }
    ,
         {
          name:"CustomerCode",
          type: "text",
          regex: ""
        },
        {
          name:"CustomerName", 
          type: "text",
          regex: ""
        },
        {
          name:"RefDate",
          type: "datetime",
          regex: ""
        }]
      }
      ,
      {
        name:"SalesOrders",
        storeType:"variable",
        properties: [
          {
            name:"OrderNo",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          }
      ,
          {
            name:"CustomerRef", 
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name:"OrderDate",
            type: "datetime",
            regex: ""
          }]
        }


  ];
  ;


  render() {

    console.log('state', this.state);
    for (let store of this.state){
        console.log(store.name);
        let chars = store["properties"]
        console.log(chars);
        for(let i=0, len=chars.length; i < len; i++){
          console.log(chars[i].name)

          // console.log(chars[i].name);
          // console.log(chars[i]["type"]);
        }

    }


  return (
    <table>
    <tbody>{this.state.map((item, key) =>{

             return (
                <tr key = {key}>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.storeType}</td>

                </tr>
              )

           })}</tbody>
     </table>
  )
    // let dataStores = this.state.dataStores.map(store => {
    //     console.log("this the ",Object.keys(store),store.name);      
    //     return (<div><li>{store.name}</li>


    //       </div>
    //     );
    // });
  }
}

export default DataStores;
```

Comment: State in react is an object rather than an array. Initialize state as `state = { values: [{...json data}] }`.

Comment: Then map over the values.

Comment: appreciate the response but would you have any more detail / example , if you have any links to anywhere i could review that would also help me a lot thanks. i have map over objects in state before where the entire object has a consistent structure but i cant seem to bring any of those examples across to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, the following approach is much better.

Check it out on sandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-meadow-f6hpz?fontsize=14

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class DataStores extends Component {
  state = {
    values: [
      {
        name: "PODs",
        storeType: "fixed",
        properties: [
          {
            name: "PODNo",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name: "CustomerCode",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name: "CustomerName",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name: "RefDate",
            type: "datetime",
            regex: ""
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        name: "SalesOrders",
        storeType: "variable",
        properties: [
          {
            name: "OrderNo",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name: "CustomerRef",
            type: "text",
            regex: ""
          },
          {
            name: "OrderDate",
            type: "datetime",
            regex: ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    // console.log('state', this.state);
    // for (let store of this.state){
    //     console.log(store.name);
    //     let chars = store["properties"]
    //     console.log(chars);
    //     for(let i=0, len=chars.length; i < len; i++){
    //       console.log(chars[i].name)

    //       // console.log(chars[i].name);
    //       // console.log(chars[i]["type"]);
    //     }

    // }

    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.values.map((item, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.storeType}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
    // let dataStores = this.state.dataStores.map(store => {
    //     console.log("this the ",Object.keys(store),store.name);
    //     return (<div><li>{store.name}</li>

    //       </div>
    //     );
    // });
  }
}

export default DataStores;
```

Comment: thanks you for that it made it much easier to see the changes, taking it a level further then from my object i have a nest object on each "store" called Properties i can loop through them fine with console.log with for (let store of this.state.values){
        console.log("the store is:",store.name,"and the type is ",store.storeType);
        let chars = store["properties"]
        for(let i=0, len=chars.length; i < len; i++){
          console.log(chars[i].name)
  
        }

    }

Comment: Mark it as the correct answer if it helped you. This will help future readers.

Comment: Remember that the state is supposed to be an object, which is a container for other properties of your component. You CANNOT inject values directly into the state as you have done. I suggest you read up some more about React Fundamentals.

Comment: sorry but how can i add below the <td>{item.storeType}</td> my goal is a table of some kind but even to see it display in <ul> would be great.

Comment: We are here to show you the correct way of doing things. Figuring stuff out yourself is the only way to learn.

Comment: ok thanks ill try fine some more info on it just everything i have seen so far is example of single object with nested objects like contact forms